# Numpy: Walk along vector within 2d matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Consider a function `A(x(z, y), y(z))`. I want to start at arbitrary `(x, y)`, and walk along `z`. I have

- `dy/dz = 1`
- `dx/dz = z y(1-x)/(y(y+z))`. For epsilon `z`, this gives `y(1-x)/(yy)`

Now, take the following discretization:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0.01, 0.99, 100)
y = np.linspace(0.5, 2, 50)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y, indexing='ij')
A = X*Y
d = Y*(1-X)/(Y*Y)
```

Now, `A` is a 2d function in (`x`, `y`):

```
A.shape
Out[25]: (100, 50)
```

which is increasing in both dimensions by construction.

Now, **from each starting point in `A`**, I want to walk along the (`d`, 1) vector, until I reach a value above `1.5`. My resulting matrix `R` with the same shape as `A` should contain the number of grid points in `y` dimension that it took to get there. If I never arrive at that value (that is, the corresponding boundary of `A` < `1.5`), any distinguishable output (eg `nan`) would be great.

Since this is difficult to do manually, I cannot give an exact expected output. But for example, take the grid point `(85, 20)`. Let's say that in that neighborhood, `d=0.1` roughly (it is actually 0.13). That'd mean that I would want to move along the (1, 10) diagonal locally, until I reach `A : A >= 1.5`. In this case, I want to walk from `A[85, 20]` up to `A[85+2, 20+20]`, the first point above `1.5`, with value of

```
A[85+2, 20+20]
Out[51]: 1.5023964131106988
```

So, I walked 20 grid points along `z`. This means that my resulting matrix `R` has `R[85, 20] == 20`.

I'm both interested in high efficiency ways of doing this, as well as worse performing but more precise solutions. In any case, my solution has to build on the given matrices.

---

**To provide some more intuition about what I'm trying to achieve**, consider `dx/dz = 0`. In that case, I could simply

```
positive = A > 1.5
iX, iY = np.meshgrid(np.arange(100), np.arange(50), indexing='ij')
gridsMove = positive.argmax(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
R = np.maximum(gridsMove-iY, 0).astype(float)
# prune those here where we never arrive (argmax yields `0`, non robust test but works here)
R[gridsMove.repeat(50, axis=1) == 0] = np.nan
```

However, in my example, I cannot `argmax(axis=1)`, since I'm walking on more than one axis. I'd have to do `argmax(axis=0.1)` or something along those lines...